# How much damage does each bounce do with the Mutalisk's Vicious Glave upgrade ... In Co-op?

Tags: starcraft-2

The long-awaited sequel to an almost 2-year-old [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225699). Not much to it other than: How much damage does each bounce do with BOTH the Vicious Glave and the Sundering Glave upgrades?

Vicious Glave: Mutalisk attacks bounce three more times.
Sundering Glave: Mutalisk attacks deal +9 damage to armored enemies.

Do the second through sixth bounces all do +9 damage? Do they do +5+3+3+1+1? Or is only the initial attack affected by Sundering?

Comment: Hi, the researcher of original answer here! While I feel the old urge to test and research, I have less time now, plus Co-op will be that much harder to test... So please don't rely on me this time :-)

Comment: It's amazing that you're still around if you ask me. Thanks a lot for replying anyway. I did imagine it would take a lot of testing to figure this out :P